# what's the meaing of the '~' in makefile?

Tags: makefile

I just started to learn how to write makefile.Then I followed the tutorial [on the website](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/).I can't understand the meaning of '~' of the last line of the Makefile5 in this tutorial.I have read the explain of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html#Wildcards) for this wildcard, but it seems that these cases don't match the usage of the below.

```
rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Comment: I don't think the tilde (~) character has a meaning in a Makefile. This is a system command (rm) and the tilde is thus interpreted by the sysem, not by GNU make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilde at the end of files simply means they are some kind of backups created by text editors.
You can find a little discussion about this type of files here: [What does the tilde at the end of a file name stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for)

Answer (score 1):

rm -f *~ just removes file with names ending with a tilde (~)